# You can't cast two spells (excluding cantrips) in a turn if you're using an action and bonus action. What about reactions?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Following off of this question [Is it possible to cast multiple spells per turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/74039/is-it-possible-to-cast-multiple-spells-per-turn), I have a question: Specifically, something like Warlock's Hellish Rebuke isn't cast in a bonus action, so can you cast, say, that, eldritch blast, and healing word all in the same set of turns?  What about...well, any spell that costs an *action,* and Hellish Rebuke?