# Can you Fog Cloud and then Misty Step away in the same round?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Since Fog Cloud requires an Action and Misty Step a Bonus Action, you could cast them both in then same turn.

My questions is whether you can use Fog Cloud centered where you are and Misty Step to flee from there, so your enemies can't see where you step into.

Question arises because Misty Step says that you teleport somewhere you can see.

If it's not possible, would there be any way to do the same effect using this two spells? (teleporting but not letting enemies know where thanks to the Fog Cloud).

Comment: Similar: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49532/casting-multiple-spells-in-a-single-round

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This doesn't work. To start with, you can't cast a bonus action spell and another leveled spell in the same turn.

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You
>   must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell,
>   provided that you haven’t already taken a bonus action
>   this turn. You can’t cast another spell during the same
>   turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.

Secondly, the *Fog Cloud* spell makes an area heavily obscured.

> A heavily obscured area—such as darkness, opaque
>   fog, or dense foliage—blocks vision entirely. A creature
>   effectively suffers from the blinded condition (see
>   appendix A) when trying to see something in that area.

In case the blinded condition needs explaining,:

> A blinded creature can’t see and automatically fails any
>   ability check that requires sight.

*Misty Step* lets you teleport to somewhere you can see - you can't see anything if you're in a *Fog Cloud*, so you can't use *Misty Step* at all.

Thirdly, it doesn't matter whether enemies can see where you teleport **from**. You want to hide the location you're teleporting **to**, so this is all pointless anyway.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the obvious reasons (blinded condition) but also that you want to hide where you teleport TO, not FROM.  So many people also forget or have no idea that you can't cast two non cantrip spells in the same turn, no matter if one of them takes a Bonus action or not.

Comment: @Airatome This is a bit nitpicky but it can come up: the restriction is on casting anything but a cantrip with a casting time of one action on the same turn you cast a bonus action speld. An Eldritch Knight can cast two spells with a casting time of 1 action using Action Surge.

Comment: Why do you say "you can't see anything if *you're* in a Fog Cloud"? The quote contradicts this: "A creature effectively suffers from the blinded condition when *trying to see something* in that area", not "when *it is* in that area".

Comment: @enkryptor the actual wording is "its area is Heavily Obscured" and the definition of Heavily Obscured is "A creature in a heavily obscured area effectively suffers from the blinded condition." with a specific callout that it "blocks vision entirely." You cannot see into, out of, within, or through a Fog Cloud spell.

Comment: @guildsbounty the "A creature in a heavily obscured area effectively suffers from the blinded condition" part was corrected in the errata - https://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PH-Errata-V1.pdf The errata says "A heavily obscured area **doesn’t blind you**, but you
are effectively blinded when you try to see something obscured by it".

Comment: @enkyrptor Correct, but as it says "A heavily obscured area doesn’t blind you, but you are effectively blinded when you try to *see something obscured by it."* (Emphasis Mine). If you are in a Fog Cloud, *everything* you try to see is obscured by the Heavy Obscuration of the Fog Cloud, because it entirely surrounds you. It blocks line of sight. In short...you cannot see through Heavy Obscuration. If there's a massive fog bank between you and your friend...you can't just magically see your friend since he's not actually in the fog bank. the fog bank blocks your line of sight.

Answer (score 5):

You can't use Misty Step inside the Fog Cloud because Misty Step requires that you be able to see your destination.

> ...to an unoccupied space that you can see. PHB page 280

The rules for spell casting also indicate that you cannot cast anything but a cantrip in the same round that you cast a spell.

> You can’t cast another spell during the same turn, except for a
>   cantrip with a casting time of 1 action. PHB page 201

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible as stated because you cannot cast two leveled spells in the same round.

> You can’t cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action. PHB page 201

That said, there *is* a way to achieve something close to what you want though - Minor Illusion is a cantrip that can create a 5' cube "image of an object."  Create a boulder or box that you can crouch in, then you can misty step away out of it - because you can see through your own illusions as you know them to be false.

> If a creature discerns the illusion for what it is, the illusion becomes faint to the creature. PHB page 260

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you're outside or in a room big enough, you could cast *levitate* on you before everything (even better have some cast it on you).  You move to your spot and cast *fog cloud* and then you can use your movement to go up (as you are under levitate) and when out of the fog cloud use *misty s*tep. But *fog cloud* has a pretty good range, so I see very few situations where going to all this trouble would make sense instead of just casting *fog cloud* on point that you are out of it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE.  Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to see how a Q&A site works.  A key is to answer the question as asked.  Your answer needs to more clearly spell out how you can accomplish all of that *in the same round*. (If possible)  A supported answer relies on more than "a neat idea" [so supporting this answer with sources](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer), or how a ruling was arrived at when playing at your table, will improve you answer. Also, identify what is and isn't possible, per the last paragraph of the question. Again, welcome, and Happy Gaming!