# What's the maximum amount of lines from Sunbeam possible within a single turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, optimization

I noticed that *sunbeam* allows you to to create multiple lines within a single turn. What's the maximum possible amount of *sunbeam* lines able to be  within one turn? I'm interested solely in the maximum number of beams fired, be that by allies, *glyph's of warding*, *simulacra*, etc. However, all of the beams must be fired on one turn, not throughout a round.

For reference, [the spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/sunbeam) has a casting time of 1 action and states:

> A beam of brilliant light flashes out from your hand in a 5-foot-wide, 60-foot-long line. Each creature in the line must make a Constitution saving throw. On a failed save, a creature takes 6d8 radiant damage and is blinded until your next turn. On a successful save, it takes half as much damage and isn't blinded by this spell. Undead and oozes have disadvantage on this saving throw.
>
> **You can create a new line of radiance as your action on any turn until the spell ends.**

**Rules**

- Level 20 Character, any combination of multi-classing allowed
- Only official material published by WOTC in book form is allowed. No Unearthed Arcana
- Setup is allowed, including any magical items present in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* or any other source-book. Items only present in campaign books are not allowed.
- You may have 4 allies at level 20
- *Simulacrum* is allowed
- The allies and any simulacra are allowed to cast spells.
- One Epic Boon is allowed
- Anything dependent on RNG, such as the Wild Magic Table, is not allowed.

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Casting multiple spells in a single round](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49532)'

Comment: Are you asking about only a single casting of *Sunbeam*? Or can multiple allies (or simulacra) cast it for more beams?

Comment: I edited your question a bit, if you feel that was incorrect feel free to change it

Answer (score 13):

### Infinite simulacra firing infinite beams with infinite readied actions

You are a Wizard who knows *Wish*, *Simulacrum*, and *Sunbeam*. For setup, you cast *Simulacrum* on yourself, then have your simulacrum cast *Wish* to wish for a simulacrum of you. Have the new simulacrum do likewise, and continue doing this until you have as many simulacra as you want. Each simulacrum readies a *Sunbeam* spell to be released on your signal. You give the signal, and an arbitrarily large number of sunbeams are fired.

(At some point, there won't be enough room for more simulacra within 6 light-seconds of you, so the signal will reach some of them on subsequent rounds, but if you have reached the point where relativity and speed-of-light delays are an issue, the shortcomings of D&D 5e's "physics engine" will be the least of your worries.)

Comment: It's not fancy, but it's the largest number I could come up with.

Comment: @Medix2 The infinity in the title is an oversimplification. The "real" answer in the text is "arbitrarily many".

Comment: Ah good, sorry, comment removed

Comment: @ryan If a simulacrum can cast wish on the same turn that it is wished into existence, then it could actually be infinite, not just arbitrarily large. Just make your wish recursive: I wish for a simulacrum of [Wizard] who will immediately repeat this wish and then [thing you want repeated infinitely].

Comment: @AgentPaper Using *wish* that way runs the risk of losing the ability to cast wish. Just creating the simulacrum (via the spell duplication function) is risk-free.

Comment: The signal, of course, should be "When I cast *sunbeam*." It's kinda like the Batsignal, but more burney. :)

Comment: @T.J.L. It wasn't spelled out explicitly for the sake of concision, but "wish for a simulacrum" is implied to mean "use the *wish* spell to duplicate the effect of the *simulacrum* spell".

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Oh, I know *you* were doing it properly to avoid losing *wish* completely. I was specifically addressing the comment regarding the recursive *wish*.

Comment: @T.J.L. Oh, that's right, I hadn't even considered that wishing for a simulacrum who already has an order to carry out would be going beyond duplicating a spell.

Comment: 6 light seconds is several times the earth/moon distance, just in case people were wondering.

Answer (score 3):

I always like to see what I can come up with solo, with no outside help, in one round... Here goes:

### I can do 3 lines with *sunbeam* in one turn.

Lvl 3 Sorcerer, for the Quicken Spell metamagic
Lvl 2 fighter, for Action Surge
Lvl 15 wizard, to be able to cast *sunbeam*

Procedure:

1. Quickened spell to cast *sunbeam* as a bonus action (1)
2. Action per turn to activate *sunbeam* (2)
3. Use Action Surge activate *sunbeam* again (3)

Comment: Sunbeam is on the Sorcerer spell list, no need to multiclass into wizard.

Comment: I just like wizards better, and the original build added time stop and glyph of warding, for a 4th line.. But it got to complicated...