# Is it possible to cast a quickened Fireball as a bonus action, and also use a bonus action to make an attack with Spiritual Weapon on the same turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, metamagic, action-economy, bonus-action

I started playing like a month ago, and the DM was nice enough to create a character for me and write me into the story. I've never played D&D before, but I told him I wanted to be a glass cannon who blows things up, so he made me a Divine Soul sorcerer at level 13. My Metamagics are Twinned Spell, Quickened Spell, and Careful Spell.

I've been reading up on the rules, and just found out before last session that I can use Quickened Spell to cast *fireball* as a bonus action and also cast *fire bolt* as my action for extra damage at the expense of 2 sorcery points. My DM gave me the *spiritual weapon* and *spirit guardians* spells. This brings me to my question.

**Can I, on turn 1, cast *fireball*, then cast *spiritual weapon* as a bonus action, then have the spiritual weapon move to/hit a bad guy - then on my next turn, use Quickened Spell on *fireball*, cast *fire bolt*, *and* have the weapon move to/hit the bad guy?**

I honestly don't see why not, as *spiritual weapon* doesn't require concentration like something like *animate objects*. But in the *Player's Handbook*, the rules on [bonus-action spells](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#BonusAction) says:

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of one action.

The part where it says "provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn" would imply that I can't.

But the part that says "you can't cast another spell during the same turn..." leads me to believe I might be able to, because I am not *casting* another spell, and I am also not *concentrating* on it. Like if I cast *dominate person* and tell the person to attack a bad guy, their attacks are not connected to what I do at all. In my opinion, it's a lot like casting *conjure celestial* and getting a couatl to cast/attack or dominating a monster.

Comment: Welcome to our stack! Please take the [tour] to learn more about how we operate and ou can also visit the [help] for more information.

Comment: Related on [casting multiple spells in a single round](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49532)

Comment: Are you using any houserules at your table?

Answer (score 20):

## There can be only one Bonus Action

[On your turn](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#YourTurn) you can only take one bonus action:

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

In this case, quickening a spell to cast as a bonus action is the use of your bonus action. Should you do that, then you no longer have a bonus action available to move/attack with *spiritual weapon*.

### You can't cast *fireball* and *spiritual weapon*

Unfortunately, the [spellcasting rules for how many spells you can cast on a turn](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49532) preclude you from doing this. If you are casting a levelled spell as a bonus action, you can only cast a cantrip with your action. Both those spells are levelled spells, so you can't cast both in the same turn.

Comment: This is correct by RAW. Matt Mercer popularized a house rule where characters can cast a low level spell (up to 3rd level) instead of a cantrip if they've used another level spell. This may be applied to everyone or offered as a feat (Spelldriver) at level 8. If the DM is using this houserule, then casting both *fireball* and *spiritual weapon* is allowed.

Comment: @raithyn someone's houserule or homebrew have zero impact on my answer. If OP is using one, then its important, otherwise it's not.

Comment: I would normally agree, but Andrew is a new player and that makes it especially important to recognize that a significant portion of new players (at least those who walk into the FLGS where I sometimes DM) are socialized to something that isn't RAW on this point. You don't have to agree with the houserule (I don't use it), but the fact that a player with a level 13 character wants to cast two level 3 spells stands out.

Comment: @raithyn I'm not going to assume anything in my answers and generally answer what's asked. I'll ask in comments if they're using any houserules. But given that any table can do any houserules, trying to accommodate for them all is impossible.

Answer (score 6):

#### Turn 1

Your first turn does not work as described. [The rules for spells with a casting time of 1 bonus action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/spellcasting#CastingTime):

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven't already taken a bonus action this turn. You can't cast another spell during the same turn, **except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action.**

You cannot cast both *fireball* and *spiritual weapon* in the same turn, as they are both levelled spells.

What you can do on your first turn is cast *spiritual weapon* with your bonus action, and cast *fire bolt* with your action.

#### Turn 2

The second turn does not work as described. You can only take one bonus action on your turn:

> You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available.

For your bonus action, you must choose to either quicken *fireball* or attack with your spiritual weapon, and you may also use your action to cast *fire bolt*.

Or, optimally, you cast *fireball* with your action, attack with your spiritual weapon for your bonus action, and save your sorcery points for another time.

Answer (score 3):

## You only have one bonus action

The rules include the following text regarding [bonus actions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#BonusActions) (emphasis mine):

> Various class features, spells, and other abilities let you take an additional action on your turn called a bonus action. The Cunning Action feature, for example, allows a rogue to take a bonus action. You can take a bonus action only when a special ability, spell, or other feature of the game states that you can do something as a bonus action. You otherwise don’t have a bonus action to take.
>
> **You can take only one bonus action on your turn, so you must choose which bonus action to use when you have more than one available**.

You can only use one bonus action, so if you use one to cast a quickened spell, you cannot also use one to move the spiritual weapon.

### On casting *fireball* and *spiritual weapon*

The section on [spells with a casting time of a bonus action](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#BonusAction) states (emphasis mine):

> A spell cast with a bonus action is especially swift. You must use a bonus action on your turn to cast the spell, provided that you haven’t already taken a bonus action
> this turn. **You can’t cast another spell during the same turn, except for a cantrip with a casting time of 1 action**.

So even though *fireball* has a casting time of 1 action and *spiritual weapon* has a casting time of 1 bonus action, they cannot actually be cast on the same turn because *fireball* is not a cantrip.