# Can I cast 3 spells (1 Bonus Action, a 1 Action cantrip, and 1 Reaction) on the same turn? Does the order of the spells cast matter?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

In Dungeons and Dragons 5th edition, can I cast Expeditious Retreat (cast time 1 Bonus Action), the cantrip spell Fire Bolt (cast time 1 Action), and Shield (cast time 1 Reaction) when I am hit by an attack on the same turn?

Does the order of the spells cast matter? I.E. Shield, Fire Bolt, and Expeditious Retreat?

So for example, can I cast Expeditious Retreat as a bonus action, move provoking an opportunity attack from an enemy, cast Shield as a reaction to deflect the attack and then from range attack the enemy with the cantrip Fire Bolt?

Or can I move causing the opportunity attack, cast Shield as a reaction, cast Expeditious Retreat as a bonus action and then from range attack it with the cantrip Fire Bolt?

Does it matter the order of movement and spells cast?

Comment: This is for D&D 5e, right?

Comment: Pretty sure it'd have to be,  bonus action as far as I know is a 5E only term... @Ifusaso

Comment: Seems like it may be answered by [Casting multiple spells in a single round](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/49532/42375)